# How to train muscle which goes from buttocks to the waist?

Tags: exercise, muscle, skiing

This year I have returned to alpine skiing and found myself relatively fit for quite intensive skiing session (up to 10 runs per hour for 3-4 hours straight twice a day for 5 days) except for two things where my body failed.

First one - on the fourth day the muscle which goes from buttocks to the waist (left one) started to hurt a lot in its upper part at the beginning of every right turn I did. There is a very specific movement at the beginning of a ski turn when you sit down and at the same moment bend your knees inside the turn. Except for this specific movement this muscle has never troubled me and I do bends touching my toes every day and squats every other day.

So there is a question - what exercise I could add to my routine to train this muscle?

Comment: are there actually 2 things or one?

Comment: @Sebas second problem described [there](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12306/bodyweight-exercises-to-increase-legs-strength)

Comment: I can't tell what muscle you're describing, so the specific PT-type exercises are unknown, but deadlifts always help with weak backs. You might have to rehab before they're a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to strengthen your lower back and there are plenty of exercises but, unfortunately they often times are neglected. Some examples:

Superman (lie on your stomach and lift your legs and arms about 6 inches off the ground, for added strength and intensity place your hands together, palms facing outwards, and move them in unison to your sides and repeat. It looks similar to the breast stroke in swimming)

Reverse plank leg lifts (toes point upwards and arms shoulder length apart, fingers facing forward. push up and settle into the "reverse plank." From there alternate bringing your each knee as close to your chest as you can.)

There are a ton of other examples online.